# My headphones temporarily disconnect when volume gets too loud on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: sound, headphones, 21.04

I'm using USB headphones (Razer Kraken Kitty Edition) and any time the audio spikes for any reason whatsoever (watching a loud video, someone screams in a discord call etc) My headphones completely disconnect for about 3 seconds. I can post any logs if needed, I'm just unsure what I would need to post.

Comment: It could be a safety feature  (I have various safety headsets that cut off for a time when volume exceeds a preset maximum; in the devices I'm talking about that's the intention - but I know some music/pc headsets do the same at certain decibel ratings - if you lower the volume and re-play where it cut out, the sound will not cut-out if volume is low enough to not hurt your eardrums).  Note: this may not be your issue; just what you describe fits safety features.

Comment: Yeah, but I've been using this headset for about a year and i had no problems on windows, nor on Ubuntu 20.10, only once i upgraded to 21.04

Answer (score 0):

How do you turn the safety feature off? I don't care about my ears and my friends voice disconnects my headphones every time she starts talking

Answer (score 0):

I recently found that for some odd reason disabling the brightness feature in the synapse fixes the problem for good. Give that a try.